# Is it bad practice to make sure code is "copy-pastable"?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13071980) in which I added a missing brace that got rejected for the following (boilerplate) reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I have no clue why that would be. Is making code "copy-pastable" considered unnecessary (since most people can just add the missing brace anyway if they're using the code)?

Comment: I don't think that was the reason, it's pretty clear that the question isn't about syntactic error in code...

Comment: I would have refrained from adding the spaces between the operator and its arguments; that's a stylistic preference that some reviewers might get hung up on.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Should I go ahead and make the same suggested edit without adding the spaces between the operator and its operands? That's what was wrong with the original edit? Because the code still looks "wrong" to me (and the typo isn't the problem in the code, that is pretty clear).

Comment: I would leave it. If someone can't figure out that their copy-pasta is lacking a brace, then they need to learn the language... Also, this is one question among the thousands coming in every day. It might be time to let go :).